# Win32/Dll: The address that is jumped to when a DLL function is called?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, assembly, x86

When a "call" instruction is executed to call a DLL exported function, it sets the EIP to the address of the function stored in the DLL. If another program that is being executed at the same time, calls this same function that belongs to this same DLL, will the jump address be the same?

Comment: Why does it matter? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why ask this? How could this knowledge benefit you? In virtual address space, the answer is "maybe, but you should not count on it anyway".

Comment: Because I want to know if the instance of a DLL is something that belongs to the process or something else. If a DLL is used by many programs at the same time, does it mean that this DLL will have many instances?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is *it depends*.

DLLs are organized in sections and each section *can be shared* by many processes. Usually only are shared only code sections (*when DLL is loaded at the same base address*) and each process has its *private data section*.

One of the advantages of DLL is that you share their code between many processes (then you save system memory because the system won't load many instances of them). Of course data can't (usually) be shared so it must be *duplicated* for each instance.

It means that **usually** the memory for DLL code is shared between different processes then it **may** have the same address. I said "may" because of [Virtual Address Space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), even if the memory is shared it's not granted that it has the same address on every process. For a quick test use `GetProcAddress` and run the process many times to compare the function address, you can use this simple program from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void _tmain()
{
    typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO);

   SYSTEM_INFO si;
   ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(SYSTEM_INFO));

   PGNSI fnGetNativeSystemInfo = reinterpret_cast<PGNSI>(GetProcAddress(
       GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")),  "GetNativeSystemInfo"));

   std::cout << fnGetNativeSystemInfo << std::endl;
}
```

You should see (usually) the same address for each exported function but you may not. It's never a good idea to rely on this behavior. Ok, this is the story but something changed in the past years because of ASLR, take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista.aspx) too.

If you have to share data between processes using the same DLL you better use some shared memory, take a look to [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

As other program(s)/processes are mapped to their own separate address space, I doubt the address will be the same.